# perl6 IO::Socket::Async server dies with the exception: connection reset by peer

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, async-await, echo, raku

Here is the echo server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
my $port = 3333 ;
say "listen port $port" ;

react {
    my $ids = 0 ;
    whenever IO::Socket::Async.listen('0.0.0.0', $port ) -> $conn {
        my $id = $ids++ ;
        $conn.print( "$id: hello\n") ;
        whenever $conn.Supply.lines -> $line {
            say "$id: $line" ;
            $conn.print( "$id : $line\n") ;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
my $port = 3333 ;
my $conn = await IO::Socket::Async.connect('localhost', $port );
$conn.print: "{time}\n";

#$conn.Supply.tap(-> $v { print $v });

sleep 1 ;
$conn.close;
```

When the client connect then does not retrieve any data from the server, then closes the connection the server dies with this error:

```
listen port 3333
0: 1524671069
An operation first awaited:
  in block <unit> at ./server2.p6 line 5

Died with the exception:
    connection reset by peer
      in block <unit> at ./server2.p6 line 5

X::AdHoc+{X::Await::Died}: connection reset by peer
```

How do I gracefully catch network errors so the server is more robust?

Comment: Is that with or without the commented out line?

Comment: When you uncomment the tap it does not die with the connection resent by peer. However I found this issue when I was doing some simple volume tests. With more volume I intermittently got this error, I feel it was a timing issue, connections closed by client when a pending messages have not been read.

Comment: `$conn.close` works asynchronously, and returns a `Promise` that can be `await`ed. Not doing so means the program may end before the connection is closed by the client, which would result in the error observed now and then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to handle the case when a `Supply` (or any awaitable, like a `Promise`) underlying a `whenever` quits (or when the `Promise` is broken), you can install a `QUIT` handler inside the whenever. It works a lot like an exception handler, so it will want you to either match the exception somehow, or just `default` if you want to treat all quit causes as "fine".

```
whenever $conn.Supply.lines -> $line {
    say "$id: $line" ;
    $conn.print( "$id : $line\n") ;
    QUIT {
        default {
            say "oh no, $_";
        }
    }
}
```

This will output "oh no, connection reset by peer" and continue running.

Comment: my $listen = IO::Socket::INET.new(:listen, :localhost<localhost>, :localport(3333)); will also die with the error: X::AdHoc: Could not receive data from socket: Connection reset by peer. QUIT or CATCH do not trap this errro.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a non-async socket. I assume I'm supposed to use `$listen` to `accept` a client socket, read its `.lines` and use your client code from the question to connect to it?

Comment: Here is the example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032392/perl6-iosocketinet-could-not-receive-data-from-socket-connection-reset-by-p)