# perl6 IO::Socket::INET Could not receive data from socket: Connection reset by peer

Tags: sockets, raku

Sample server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
my $listen = IO::Socket::INET.new(:listen, :localhost<localhost>, :localport(3333));
loop {
    my $conn = $listen.accept;
    while my $buf = $conn.recv(:bin) {
        $conn.write: $buf;
    }
    $conn.close;
}
```

Client:

```
#!/use/bin/env perl6
my $c = IO::Socket::INET.new(:host<localhost>, :port(3333));
$c.print: "{time}\n";
#say $c.recv; #commented out on purpose
sleep 1 ;
$c.close ;
```

server error:

`Could not receive data from socket: Connection reset by peer
    in block <unit> at server4.p6 line 5`

In the server on each of the blocks I tried `CATCH` and `QUIT`. How should I catch this error?

Comment: Better still, you should prevent it, by not writing data that the peer isn't reading, or conversely by reading all the data that is being sent.

Comment: In theory yes, but for server code should not crash when a client misbehaves. I think this would also happen if the network drops in the middle of the session.

Comment: That's basically [the code from the example in docs](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Socket::INET). If it crashes the server, there's definitely an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server needs to catch the error in the loop block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
my $listen = IO::Socket::INET.new(:listen, :localhost<localhost>, :localport(3333));
loop {
    my $conn = $listen.accept;
    while my $buf = $conn.get {
        $conn.print: $buf;
    }
    $conn.close;
    CATCH { default { say .^name, ': ', .Str ,  " handled in $?LINE";}}
}
```

Output of server reports the error and stays running to accept new connections:

```
perl6 --ll-exception server.p6
X::AdHoc: Could not receive data from socket: Connection reset by peer handled in 9
```