# Handling connection failures with IO::Socket::Async

Tags: asynchronous, raku, cro

I'm working on a small project using IO::Socket::Async. I'm trying write some tests to make sure I'm handling a connection loss properly but my initial attempts didn't go as planned. I thought using a QUIT phaser would work but that didn't give any response in the tests I tried closing the supply but that isn't giving the results I was hoping for. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to handle a connection loss with IO::Socket::Async?

An example of the supply where I try to use the quit is below. Since it isn't working how I expected. I am not sure if I am going about this correctly.

```
supply whenever $connection -> $event {
    if $event ~~ /event message/ {
       emit { status => $event };
    }
    QUIT {
        .note;
        say 'conection lost';
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026525/perl6-iosocketasync-server-dies-with-the-exception-connection-reset-by-peer `LAST { $conn.close ; }
            QUIT { default { $conn.close ; say "oh no, $_";}}
            CATCH { default { say .^name, ': ', .Str ,  " handled in $?LINE";}}`  http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Simple_database#Perl_6

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways a connection might be terminated:

- EOF, which we consider an "orderly" close. The `whenever` subscription is much like a loop, and the `LAST` phaser triggers on orderly end of the stream. So, to handle this case, use `LAST`.
- Erroneous termination, such as connection reset by peer, which will trigger the `QUIT` as you wrote (though you need `QUIT { default { note $_ } }` to actually handle it, just as with `CATCH`).

It seems that quite a few more cases are considered "orderly" (that is, the EOF case) than at least *I* expected. For example, run a server like this:

```
react {
    whenever IO::Socket::Async.listen('localhost', 4242) -> $conn {
        whenever $conn -> $stuff {
            $conn.print($stuff);
        }
    }
}
```

And a client like this:

```
my $conn = await IO::Socket::Async.connect('localhost', 4242);
react {
    whenever $conn -> $stuff {
        say "Got back $stuff";
        LAST {
            say "Connection closed";
            done;
        }
        QUIT {
            default {
                say "Connection lost: $_";
                done;
            }
        }
    }

    whenever Supply.interval(1) {
        $conn.print("hello $_\n");
    }
}
```

Then Ctrl+C the server, and - at least on my local setup (Ubuntu in a VM) - it triggered the `LAST`. I wondered if this could be some kind of bug, so traced it all the way back into the VM's I/O binding, and no, we really are getting EOF passed to us from the operating system in that case, not an error. Sticking the server on a separate machine, and then disconnecting the wifi on my local one, was enough to trigger the `QUIT` case with a "Connection reset by peer".

In summary, `QUIT` is the right way to handle erroneous loss of connection, but `LAST` is triggered by EOF, and that shows up in some cases that we might consider "connection loss"; only the protocol being spoken atop of the socket can really determine whether this was an unexpected time for things to come to an end.